# mysql server ssl setup error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to enable ssl on mysql running on ubuntu

```
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value                       |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| admin_ssl_ca                        |                             |
| admin_ssl_capath                    |                             |
| admin_ssl_cert                      |                             |
| admin_ssl_cipher                    |                             |
| admin_ssl_crl                       |                             |
| admin_ssl_crlpath                   |                             |
| admin_ssl_key                       |                             |
| have_openssl                        | DISABLED                    |
| have_ssl                            | DISABLED                    |
| mysqlx_ssl_ca                       |                             |
| mysqlx_ssl_capath                   |                             |
| mysqlx_ssl_cert                     |                             |
| mysqlx_ssl_cipher                   |                             |
| mysqlx_ssl_crl                      |                             |
| mysqlx_ssl_crlpath                  |                             |
| mysqlx_ssl_key                      |                             |
| performance_schema_show_processlist | OFF                         |
| ssl_ca                              | /opt/mysql/keys/ca.pem      |
| ssl_capath                          |                             |
| ssl_cert                            | /opt/mysql/keys/tls.pem     |
| ssl_cipher                          |                             |
| ssl_crl                             |                             |
| ssl_crlpath                         |                             |
| ssl_fips_mode                       | OFF                         |
| ssl_key                             | /opt/mysql/keys/tls-key.pem |
| ssl_session_cache_mode              | ON                          |
| ssl_session_cache_timeout           | 300                         |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
27 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`

There is no Selinux enabled.

```
2024-03-13T13:33:00.962002Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013595] [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.
2024-03-13T13:33:00.962052Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
2024-03-13T13:33:00.983378Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011302] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Failed at SSL configuration: "SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key"'
```

I verified that mysql user has perms to these files

`sudo -u mysql cat /opt/mysql/keys/tls-key.pem  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Any one seen this before?

Comment: which mysql version are you using

Comment: mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

Comment: see if you followed all steps here, inclcluding generating a key

Comment: have you set `ssl-ca = `? what are the permissions and users of your SSL fils? have you set `tls_version=` to anything, or what is its value? Problem could also be not following the instructions to the letter described in mySQL 8.0 Reference Manual section 6.3.3.2 and using openssl

Comment: These are self signed certs, not the mysql generated ones. Is it possible that incorrectly generated certs could result in this error? If so, how do I check

Comment: @Ron, yes the ssl-ca is set, I did not explicitly set the tls version, I think default is v1.2. Also this is error is happening during server startup, when I try to connect using clients I get "ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't support it"